# how to use variables in tinyMCE.init tiny mce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Can we use variables in tinyMCE.init() ? I want to decide the available set of buttons on value of formatselect. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You only have to make sure that this variables are accessible from the tinymce init function. For example:

```
var content_file = "/css/content.css";

tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "code,...",

        content_css: content_file,  // used here

        language : 'de'
});
```

You may also use a scriptlanguage liek perl or php to dynamically create your javascript code.

Comment: Almost. The variable doesn't need to be accessible from with the init function, but from the code that calls it (or to be more specific, creates that list of settings)

Comment: I'm trying this - 
    buttonToolBar:"bold,italic";
    tinyMCE.init({
         mode : "exact",
         theme : "advanced",
         elements : "textAreaId",
         theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
         theme_advanced_layout_manager: "SimpleLayout",
         theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before :"formatselect",
         plugins : "code",
         theme_advanced_disable :buttonToolBar
 });
But it fails with error buttonToolBar not defined. :(

Comment: @KutePHP: try: buttonToolBar = "bold,italic"; ('=' instead of ':' when setting the variable at the beginning)

Comment: init fails and no mce instance is loaded.

Comment: does it gets inititialized when you do not use the parameter theme_advanced_disable at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what you were asking. Before the `init()`, but after the `<script>` be sure to declare the variable

```
-- var buttonToolBar="bold,italic";
```

Then, be sure to type the setting correctly

```
-- theme_advanced_disable: buttonToolBar,
```

(I noticed that there was no underscore between theme and advanced in your post)
This worked for me, and the `[Bold]` and `[Italic]` buttons were not visible on my editor.